# Why is google chart api adding a div on every draw()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, formatting

I call chart.draw() every second after updating a google dataTable. Each time, a new element is added to the end of the body tag:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: -1000px; left: -1000px; white-space: nowrap; display: none;"><svg></svg></div>
```

A script is also added to the head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%7CRoboto:medium">
```

I have not included any fonts. The charts I am loading are:

```
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart', 'line', 'controls', 'bar', 'table']
    });
```

It is messing up formatting of the page.
How do I get it to stop?

Answer (score 0):

After much experimenting, I found the source of the issue.
The google charts were in a `<div>` with the CSS property `display: flex;`
And each chart had a `height: 50%` property.

Apparently when google draws a chart, it adds space to fill up its flexbox. The flexbox would then resize and then they would keep bouncing off each other.
I may be wrong about the exact mechanics, but that's my theory.